# Python Regex to find incomplete opening and closing brackets

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to find both opening and closing brackets that are incomplete. The following are examples.

```
"[[lang:foreign]"  "[lang:foreign]]"  "[[beep"  "[beep"  "hello]"  "lang:foreign]"
```

I have tried multiple regex expressions such as:

```
\[([^()]|(?R))*\] Or
[^\[*(\[.*\))[^\]]* Or just
\W\s?\W
```

I know none of them are going to work.

My main goal is to find an incomplete bracket such as `[beep or [[beep or beep]` and then add a special identifying character before it.
So it would look like `#specialC#[beep or #specialC#[[beep or #specialC#beep]`

Comment: Not a problem that you should be trying to solve with a regex

Comment: Do the brackets (either opening or closing) always appear together?
Also, can you tell if the test-cases that you have provided are positive or negative?

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa I have this big json file and it contains tags that are complete like [text] but some are not complete like [text or text]. And my test cases are negative. Thanks!

Comment: See if this works for your problem \[+.?\]+

Comment: These are called "unbalanced brakets" or "unbalanced parentheses" and finding them is a [common coding challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180567/checking-for-balanced-brackets-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

This seems easier without regex  (although there is probably a more efficient approach).

Convert the string to a list of characters (to simplify character substitution while looping), keep a list of open bracket index values, remove open bracket index values from the list when matching close brackets are found, replace any close brackets encountered before a corresponding open bracket, replace any open brackets remaining in the list of index values after the entire string has been checked, then join the list to return a string that includes the replaced character values.

```
def unmatched(s):
    chars = list(s)
    opened = []
    for i, c in enumerate(chars):
        if c == '[':
            opened.append(i)

        if c == ']':
            if not opened:
                chars[i] = ']*UNMATCHED*'
            else:
                opened.pop()

    for i in opened:
        chars[i] = '*UNMATCHED*['

    return ''.join(chars)
```

Example output:

```
d = ['[[lang:foreign]', '[lang:foreign]]', '[[beep', '[beep', 'hello]', 'lang:foreign]']
for s in d:
    print(unmatched(s))

# *UNMATCHED*[[lang:foreign]
# [lang:foreign]]*UNMATCHED*
# *UNMATCHED*[*UNMATCHED*[beep
# *UNMATCHED*[beep
# hello]*UNMATCHED*
# lang:foreign]*UNMATCHED*
```